# Layover in USA with B2 visa

Tags: visas, usa, transit, b1-b2-visas, bulgarian-citizens

I am traveling from Cancun to London with a Bulgarian passport. Last year (2017) I spent 3 months traveling through the USA and my visa (B2) is valid until 4th of March.

The flight I am looking for is at the end of April and beginning of May with 2 layovers in America. Because, unfortunately, Bulgaria is not part of the Visa Waiver Program, I am traveling with a B2 instead of an ESTA.

My question is, would I be allowed to transit in the USA and if so, are they going to give me another visa?

Comment: Do you mean you will transit the US *after* your B2 visa expires?

Comment: Are you going to apply for a new visa covering the April-May timeframe?

Comment: Yes the transition is after the visa expired but in order to extend the visa I have to travel oversea.

Comment: My question is would I be refused for layover if my visa is expired since am not travelling with Esta?

Comment: If your visa is expired, you won't be able to transit in the US.

Comment: "In order to extend the visa I have to travel overseas": why do you think that? You can apply at the US consulate in Cancun.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot transit the United States with an expired US visa (with the exception of [automatic revalidation](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1218/~/automatic-revalidation-for-certain-temporary-visitors), which doesn't apply here). You'll need to apply for [a transit visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html) (or another B-2 visa; you can transit on a B visa). Unfortunately, this requires paying the visa fee and an interview at a US Embassy or Consulate. You'll have to weigh whether the time and expense of getting the visa is worth any potential savings in airfare (British Airways has a direct flight CUN-LGW).

That you've been issued a visa before and, presumably, did not overstay would be a good sign that you are perhaps likely to receive another visa, but there is no way to predict that for sure.